# xargs: zip: No such file or directory

Tags: zip, xargs

By using the below command I am just trying to search specific files in a directory and zip them all.

```
find /var/www/httpdocs/reports/files/ -type f -iname "report_202312*" -print0 | xargs -0 zip -r /var/www/httpdocs/reports/files/reports.zip
```

If I run find command independently then its running fine and showing the result. But when running above full command giving

> xargs: zip: No such file or directory

error.

Please help me to solve this, its over ubuntu.

Comment: Is the `zip` package actually installed on your system?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the issue, zip extension installled in php and I never think in this way,  now giving -  Command 'zip' not found, but can be installed with:
apt install zip
thanks

Comment: @steeldriver That looks like an answer

Comment: @DanielT done thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

```
xargs: zip: No such file or directory
```

basically<sup>1</sup> means that an executable program named `zip` is not found within the environment's `PATH`. Since `xargs` *is* found, and both by default live in `/usr/bin/`, we can rule out an issue with the `PATH` environment variable itself and conclude that `zip` simply isn't installed, so fix that by running

```
sudo apt install zip
```

(or `sudo apt install --reinstall zip` if the package *is* installed, but the program itself was manually deleted).

---

1. there's a corner-case possibility that it is found, but is missing dependent libraries or has the wrong binary architecture - see for example

- [Why does sh say "not found" when it's definitely there?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18061/why-does-sh-say-not-found-when-its-definitely-there)
- [Linux executable fails with "File not found" even though the file is there and in PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378301/linux-executable-fails-with-file-not-found-even-though-the-file-is-there-and-i)